# Can I install IIS7 express on Windows XP

Tags: iis, iis-7, windows-xp, iis-express

I installed IIS7 beta 3 through Web Platfrom Installer, when I try to connect to it from Internet Information Services (IIS) 7 Manager, I get the following error message:

could not load file or assembly microsoft.web.administration...

Edit: I am running XP SP3 and I do not have IIS 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question it appears that you are looking for ways to configure IIS Express. As Kat implies, IIS Express doesn't ship IIS Manager like tool (unfortunately).

---

One way to configure IIS Express short of editing configuration file directly is to use command line tool appcmd.exe that can be found in installation directory of IIS Express.(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690358/iisexpress-user-interface)

Answer (score 2):

According to their official documentation on this it can be installed on XP SP3

> Q: What OS and SKUs are supported?
>
> A: IIS Express is supported on the
>   following operating systems: Windows
>   XP SP3+ Windows Vista SP1+ Windows 7
>   Windows Server 2008 Windows Server
>   2008 R2 Windows Server 2003 SP2+

Answer (score 0):

If you try connecting to your IIS Express instance using [IIS Remote Manager](https://www.iis.net/download/IISManager) or "proper" IIS, then it is not supported.

In addition to this, remote access to IIS Express is not enabled by default. Refer to this [blog post](http://blogs.iis.net/vaidyg/archive/2010/07/29/serving-external-traffic-with-webmatrix-beta.aspx) to enable remote access to IIS Express/WebMatrix.