# GUI template for IIS express

Tags: asp.net, webserver, iis-express, web-development-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IISExpress User Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690358/iisexpress-user-interface)

I've installed IIS 7.5 express on my local machine (Windows XP + SP3).

I am able to access IIS express from cmdline using  (IISExpress /?) . I want to create a ASP.net website and configure it to run in IIS Express .I searched the GUI for IIS express but could not find anywhere

Please tell me where i can find the GUI for IISExpress

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use VBScripts to manage IIS. Check the Microsoft Technet Script Center or EggheadCafe.com.

If you google "IIS script management" you'll probably find a ton of results.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your response .Atn this time I am looking for a way to manage IIS express using the GUI templates  .It is not my intention to automate IIS expresses functions using VBScripts or powershell scripts.