# IIS 7 Configuration - Is everything configurable via web.config?

Tags: iis-7, iis-express

Is everything in IIS 7 configurable with the web.config?
Is there anything that can't be configured with web.config?

I am using IIS Express and am can't figure out how to do some of the configurations I can do in IIS 7 because I don't have the GUI to configure things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there will be a lot of things that cannot be configure in web.config, such as bindings, permissions, logging, etc.

Try this for an option on how to configure : [IIS Express Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690358/iisexpress-user-interface)