# Why websites created in WebMatrix not visible in IIS?

Tags: iis, webmatrix-2

I have windows 7 home premium. The version of IIS is Home Premium 7.

I have created a website using DotNetNuke through WebMatrix. The files related to the website are created under the "My Documents" folder. However, when I open the IIS window, I do not see any website that I created in WebMatrix through DotNetNuke. Following are my questions:

1) I would like to understand how WebMatrix configures the website to be run without the website being visible under the IIS console?

2) Where does WebMatrix stores the configuration i.e the port assigned to Localhost (In my case it is localhost:32189)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WebMatrix does not create sites under the full version of IIS. It uses IIS Express. If you want your site to run under the full version of IIS, you need to configure that yourself.

You can usually find the IIS Express configuration file in `C:\Users\<your-username>\Documents\IISExpress\config\`. Its a file called `applicationhost.config`.

Comment: I have found that the IISExpress is installed under C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express. However when I executed IISExpress.exe file, it opened a command prompt, which showed that the IISExpress is running. Why is there no management console for IISExpress?. The icon in the system tray showed the same IIS Management icon, which the normal IIS Server management console has.

Comment: Ok. I have found the answer to my above question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690358/iisexpress-user-interface